# Manipulating multidimensional arrays with a variable

Tags: php

I want to use the value of a variable and assign it to an array.

For example - this code works:

```
$mf_hook_emails[19734]['Dept Notify'] = 'customer_service@abc.com';
```

But this code doesn't work (assigning the email address to a variable first):

```
$deptemail='customer_service@abc.com';
$mf_hook_emails[19734]['Dept Notify'] = $deptemail;
```

Comment: It will work. How are you judging that its not working?

Comment: 'But this code doesn't work' is NOT an error report. Be more specific

Comment: The email is sent when it is hardcoded but not with the variable.  I would think it would work but didn't know if there was some special syntax I was missing when using a variable in an array.

Answer (score 1):

```
$deptemail='customer_service@abc.com';
$mf_hook_emails[19734]['Dept Notify'] = $deptemail;
```

This works fine for me. `print_r($mf_hook_emails)` gives:

```
Array (
       [19734] => Array (
             [Dept Notify] => customer_service@abc.com
             )
      )
```

Answer (score 0):

You may define it like this:-

```
 $mf_hook_emails[19734]['Dept Notify'] = (string)$deptemail;
```